# Ms Access SQL to mySQL - Transform/Pivot

Tags: mysql

I am a testing my ms access database to MySQL. I am newbie in MySQL. I have this sql which is running fine in access. I want to convert it in MySQL and test it.

```
TRANSFORM IIf(Sum([price]) Is Null,0,Sum([price])) AS SumPrice
SELECT Format([AppointmentDate],"yyyy") AS [Year], IIf(Sum([SumPrice]) Is Null,0,Sum([SumPrice])) AS TotalPricePerYear
FROM tblAppointment
GROUP BY Format([AppointmentDate],"yyyy")
ORDER BY Format([AppointmentDate],"yyyy") DESC 
PIVOT Month([AppointmentDate]) In (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: i advice you to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide text formatted example and  text formatted expected results.. Then we can verify the qeury we write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT year
     , SUM(CASE WHEN month =  1 THEN price END) jan_revenue
     , SUM(CASE WHEN month =  2 THEN price END) feb_revenue
     ...
     , SUM(CASE WHEN month = 12 THEN price END) dec_revenue
FROM (SELECT tblAppointment.*
           , EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM AppointmentDate) year
           , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM AppointmentDate) month
       FROM tblAppointment 
     ) tblAppointment
GROUP BY year
```